# Can lost water pressure cause a water heater to leak/rupture?

Tags: water, water-heater, water-pressure, hot-water

I woke up this morning at 5 am to my water heater making loud noises. It had leaked all over the floor and the bathroom sink had a steady stream of hot water that wouldn't turn off. This water heater is electric and was just purchased in October 2018, so it's about 6 months old. The water pressure through the house was so low the toilet wouldn't flush.
Called the water company at 8:30 am and they said there had been an emergency crew dispatched to a water leak in my area. And at 11:00 am said there was no estimate of completion for repair and they are still working on it. 
Could this have cause my water heater to over pressurize? The warranty is covering replacement, I just want to know what happened.

Comment: What was the water heater failure mechanism? What broke and started leaking, in other words?

Comment: My husband said the bottom leaked. There was some water at the top, but not much.

Comment: Not particularly clear - but (for instance) if the water pressure rose a lot, the "temperature and pressure" relief valve **on the water heater itself** should have relieved that, even if your system does not (as mine does per current applicable code or recommendations) have another "pressure only" relief valve on the cold water supply as well.

Comment: Pressure regulator between the municipal tap and your home is installed for protecting against over pressurization damage. Do you have such a device installed?

Answer (score 1):

No, low water pressure would not cause the water heater to leak. BUT, there may have been a sever pressure SPIKE that caused the the leak that the water dept. crew was trying to fix, and that spike may have ALSO damaged your water heater.

You might want to have a peek at all of your other fixtures and water based appliances too. For example your washing machine and dishwasher have cheap little plastic valves that turn on when you do a load, they may have burst as well. But in those cases the tubs will just fill and then drain out the waste lines, so you don't know there is a problem until you go to use them, by then you have run up a huge water and sewer bill.